# Is there an Attribute that hides a property from being bound to a gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, properties, attributes

I have an object that I set as the datasource for a gridview - this works fine, I get a nice table on the page with a column for each public property.

But - I always want to hide one of the columns (but still need it available as a public property.

I'm using a clunky hide-column-on-row-created fix for now, but am looking for a better solution, like an attribute applied to the property to hide it from databinding.

Apparently this exists in winforms:

```
[Browsable(false)] // this stops Type from showing up in databound controls
public string Type { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; }
```

Can anyone suggest a similar solution for ASP.NET?

**Update:**
I marked Rex M's answer as correct, because it answers the question, but if anyone else is interested in how to do this:
What eventually worked for me was to mark the property corresponding to the column I wanted to hide as **internal** instead of public.

Comment: Can you not template your gridview and just not have that specific column in there?  I have a DB with over 100 fields, but the gridview only has 4 columns.. I did this by using a template rather than letting the gridview bind to all the columns.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring yes, but for most of these situations what you want to show in a gridview is the whole table, with perhaps one or two columns hidden. I'm hoping for a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the reflected code for `GridView.CreateAutoGeneratedColumns(PagedDataSource dataSource)`, it appears there are not any checks for attributes when it is scraping the datasource for properties. So, apparently not.

Comment: OK, can't argue with that (thanks, never thought of using reflection).